# dynamically set jquery event.data parameter

Tags: jquery, jquery-on

I have the following snippet in a `$(document).ready();` block.

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.mappin', {class_name: $(this).attr('id')}, do_showDetails);
```

I can't figure out how to correctly set the class_name field in the data parameter. I know this is where the problem is as hardcoding a value passes the data correctly.

Surely `this` is valid here?

Comment: If you're trying to pass the ID of the outer scope, probably the document, `this` is valid, but it's not the element the event handler is bound to, and why would you need to pass that this way anyhow ?

Comment: Without the rest of the code we can only guess what `this` is, I'd guess its the document. You should also say what you want it to be.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this is what you want but try this:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.mappin', function() {
    $(this).addClass($(this).attr('id'));
    do_showDetails();
});
```

Comment: well that was obvious :|